# Error on passing data back to Dropdownlist asp .net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have a dropdownlist that cannot be used for editing purpose. When button Edit is clicked inside listview where data exists, data is supposed to pass back to dropdownlist and other textboxes where the form is located outside listview. Passing data back to textboxes is ok. The problem is dropdownlist data that I want to edit was added to dropdownlist as another record. Please take a loot at picture, and I have to reselect the correct one. Otherwise, that selected data (e.g. December in picture) has no datavaluefield and it stops running if I didn't choose bottom December and click Update button. Here is my code for dropdownlist for months. Any help is appreciated for this. Thank you.

```
   public void BindMonth()
{
    ddlStartMonth.DataSource = objUIHelpers.GetAllMonths();
    ddlStartMonth.DataTextField = "StartMonthName";
    ddlStartMonth.DataValueField = "MonthId";
    ddlStartMonth.DataBind();
    ddlStartMonth.Items.Insert(0, "Select Start Month");}
```

Then, I put this method in page load like this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindMonth();
    }
}
```

This is listview data item editing

```
protected void lvEducation_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        //Delete Method will be fired when command name "Delete" inside Listview is clicked.
        case ("Delete"):

            int EducationId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);//pass Id of Experience to identify datarow to delete
           // DeleteEducationById(ExperienceId);//Call bind to delete method and pass ExperienceId as argument

            break;

        //Edit Method will fired when command name "Edit" inside Listview is clicked.
        case ("Edit"):
            EducationId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //pass Id of Experience to identify datarow to edit
            BindEducationDataToEdit(EducationId);//Call bind to edit method and pass ExperienceId as argument
            break;
    }}
```

This is part of method that triggers to pass back data to edit.

```
 public void BindEducationDataToEdit(int EducationId)
{
    Education edu = objJFUserBAL.GetEducationByIdToEdit(EducationId);

    txtAdditionalInfo.Text = edu.AdditionalInfo.ToString();
    ddlEndMonth.SelectedItem.Text = edu.mo.EndMonthName;
    }
```

When selected data is posted back for editing, I have extra data like this.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be updating the `SelectedItem.Text`. This is changing the displayed text. Instead you should be updating which item is selected.

If you do not have access to the value of the month name, you can do the following:

```
ddlEndMonth.Items.FindByText(edu.mo.EndMonthName).Selected = true;
```

which will select the item with the month text assuming one exists.

If it is possible to have an `edu.mo.EndMonthName` which does not exist in the list of items, you will want to do some checks for null and treat accordingly.

Comment: Thank a lot. It works well with your code. My problem is just solved. I added one more line of code above yours. `ddlEndMonth.ClearSelection();` to clear original selection; otherwise, it throws exception of multiple selection in ddl. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill a list manually, because auto binding is not going to let you put a "select your month" item unless you have one in your data base :

```
public void BindMonth()
{

    List<Month> listOfMonth = new List<Month>();
    Month fakeMonth = new Month();

      // you need to see your own 
      //code and try to make a fake month with these parameters you want

    fakeMonth.StartMonthName = "Select Start Month";
    fakeMonth.MonthId = 0;


    listOfmounth.Add(fakeMonth);

    foreach(Month m in objUIHelpers.GetAllMonths())
    {
       listOfMonth.Add(m)
    }

    ddlStartMonth.DataSource = listOfMonth;
    ddlStartMonth.DataTextField = "StartMonthName";
    ddlStartMonth.DataValueField = "MonthId";
    ddlStartMonth.DataBind();
    ddlStartMonth.Items.Insert(0, "Select Start Month");}
}
```